# Wget in AWS Lambda returns none

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried a python code to call wget, but it returns nothing.
Is there wget enabled in Lambda?

My sample code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import os 
    f = os.popen("wget -qO- --timeout=30 --tries=1 google.com")
    a = []
    for line in f.readlines(): 
       a.append(line)
    return a
```

But it returns an empty list.

Comment: You can use [AWS Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to load binaries in /opt/bin that you can then invoke.

Answer (score 1):

lets try to use urllib instance of wget.

```
import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://google.com')
f = open(local_filename)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I need to know whether Lambda support wget, because some of our java codes needs wget.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR - were you able to run wget in Lambda server?

Comment: So I was able to use curl -O <ServiceURL> command successfully. In my experience wget did not work for same url or any url. Can't find any aws docs stating if wget is supported in Lambda server out of the box or not.